# Using same plugin name on two different module will cause issue in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have two plugin have same name on di.xml on two different module. I doubt it has issue calling only one plugin and ignoring the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, magento will get only because the queue plugin has the index is the name of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing any sort order?? If not Try adding Sort order to your plugins in di.xml

[Check this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#declaring-a-plugin) 
The sort order decides which Plugin to be fired first